# Whose likeness was used and/or who was the voice actress for Sekhmet in the game Stargate SG-1: Unleashed?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

I would like to know whose likeness they used for the character of Sekhmet in *Stargate SG-1: Unleashed* and whether that person was also the voice actress for that character in the game.

[image]

Comment: All of the 'additional voices' listed in the end credits appears to be men's names: https://english-voice-over.fandom.com/wiki/Stargate_SG-1:_Unleashed_(2013) with the possible exception of Reid Collum

Comment: I suspect it's probably Holden Thomas. If it's the [same actor on IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm10149543/), then he would have been in his early teens when he did the voicework in 2013, and easily able to voice a youthfully androgynous goa'uld queen